# Django - Logging - How to get the class name when running function GET inside it?

Tags: python, django, logging

So I tried to create a logging for my code:

`views.py`

```
class name_of_API(generics.GenericAPIView):
    @my_logging
    @swagger_auto_schema
    def get(self, request):
        **running something
        return ...
```

`my_logging.py`

```
def func_detail(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        ex = None 
        try: 
            
            response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            log = logging.getLogger('main')
            log.info(str(func.__class__.__name__)+ ' Called success')
            print(func.__class__.__name__)
            return response
        except:
            log = logging.getLogger('internal')
            ex = Exception
            ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            log.debug(ex_type(ex_value).with_traceback(ex_traceback))
            raise  ex_type(ex_value).with_traceback(ex_traceback)
    return func_wrapper
```

format in `settings.py`

```
'format': '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d|%(levelname)s|%(process)d:%(thread)d|%(filename)s:%(lineno)d|%(module)s.%(funcName)s|%(message)s'
```

`info.log`:

> 2020-12-21 10:30:04.845|INFO|12560:11868|logger.py:11|logger.func_wrapper| function Called success

The problem here:
This row below

```
func.__class__.__name__
```

return `function` instead of `name_of_API`

Comment: Your decorator is incomplete and the the return value is  essential to the function of the decorator.

Comment: @KlausD. Hi, I just update my function, please have a look at it if you can help me out of this situation